# How to apply Coupon on the Specific Products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, coupon, helper

I want to apply the coupon on the specific product I tried:

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $helpercontext,
    Rule $rule,
 ){
    $this->_rule = $rule;
    parent::__construct($helpercontext);
 }
 public function setCoupon()
{
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend');  


    $coupon['name'] = 'Offer_asad2';
    $coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
    $coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
    $coupon['end'] = '';
    $coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
    $coupon['discount_type'] ='by_fixed';
    $coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
    $coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
    $coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
    $coupon['code'] ='NL04-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenerated but i am hard coding for testing purposes  

    $this->_rule->setName($coupon['name'])
            ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
            ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
            ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
            ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
            ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
            ->setIsActive(1)
            ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
            ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
            ->setDiscountQty(1)
            ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
            ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
            ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
            ->setCouponType(2)
            // ->setProductIds(array(1,2,3))
            // ->setProductIds(array('1','2','3'))
            ->setProductIds(1)
            ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
            ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
    $this->_rule->save();
}
```

Now the issue is this code is applying on every single `product->setProductIds(array(1,2,3))` and `->setProductIds(array('1','2','3'))` but this is not working for me,
How can I apply the I set the coupon for the specific products?

Comment: use `setProductId`, without 's'

Comment: you use it for one specific product but for more (array of)product, you use with 's'.

Comment: Yeah at the above scenario its I write it **setProductIds** n I pass the single product value but at that scenario it not gives me any error but in other cases as I mention above giver me an error **Array to String** how can I solve this?

Comment: ahh okay, you have to put it inside bracket to indicate it as an array like this:  **setProductIds([1, 2, 3])**

Comment: Sir Still have the same Problem **Notice: Array to string conversion in /home2/mako/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228**

Comment: do it also for **setCustomerGroupIds([1, 2, 3])**  and **setWebsiteIds([1])**

Comment: did it solve your issue? My doubt is, the Error **Notice: Array to string conversion...** that you are getting is during rendering response

Comment: Sir Acually firstly when the error comes then I remove every single line and check the code the Array to String error comes only when I add this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91105/discussion-between-magefms-and-asad-khan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at Last I solve this mystery we cannot apply the coupon on the specific product by using `getProductIds()` to apply the coupon on the specific product we have to add few conditions after the basic coupon code

```
 $conditions["1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine",
                "aggregator" => "all",
                "attribute" => null,
                "operator" => null,
                "value" => 1,
                "is_value_processed" => null,
            );
            $conditions["1--1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found",
                "attribute" => null,
                "operator" => null,
                "value" => 1,
                "is_value_processed" => null,
                "aggregator" => "all",
            );
            $conditions["1--1--1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                "attribute" => "sku",
                "operator" => "==",
                // "operator" => "()",
                // "value" => $couponData['general']['product_id']
                "value" => $this->getSKUU(),
            );
            $conditions["1--1--1-1"] = array
                (
                "type" => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                // "attribute" => "quote_item_row_total",
                "attribute" => "quote_item_qty",
                "operator" => "==",
                "value" => 1
            );

            $actions = array(
                "1" => array(
                        "type"          => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                        "aggregator"    => "all",
                        "value"         => "1",
                        "new_child"     => false
                ),
                "1--1" => array(
                        "type"          => "Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
                        "attribute"     => "sku",
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => $this->getSKUU()
                )
            );
```